# How can I allow email addresses from two different domains using Regex?

Tags: php, regex

I've got an small form to download some stuff. But I don't want every buddy to download it. Only from 2 specific domains you can download the stuff. So I made an  form with an email validation. But How can I add two Domains in the test of the email?
What I was trying was:

```
$test = array(
'email' => '/^[\w.+-]{2,}\@[DOMAIN1][DOMAIN2]\.[a-z]{2,6}$/',
}
```

But that didn't worked …

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are the extensions of the allowed domains fixed and known? And do you really need to use a regex? PHP's filters and array functions would work just fine here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By grouping the evaluation `()` and placing an or operator in it `|` you'll be able to handle either domain. See the below modified regex:

```
'email' => '/^[\w.+-]{2,}\@(DOMAIN1|DOMAIN2)\.[a-z]{2,6}$/',
```

Comment: @mee, fantastic, I'm glad I could be of assistance!